# Synchronize folders beetween different users

Tags: debian, synchronization

I have a server web based on Debian where I have 3 Third-level domain like this

```
a.mysite.com
b.mysite.com
c.mysite.com
```

I want to synchronize a folder between them... So if I upload a new or modified file in the folder of one of them, the same happen on the other two...

I have tried with

```
ln -s a.mysite.com/folder b.mysite.com/folder
```

as a root, but user B cannot execute the file content...

Comment: Why not just make a folder that both of them can read, modify, and execute along with its contents and upload the data there?

Comment: https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd